# Log management in cxf + spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, cxf, cxf-client

I have `Spring boot server` and it work like `proxy`. It is `SOAP service` and `SOAP client`. user call soap service on my server and my server call another soap service. Bouth services use one `WSDL`. My server implement this `WSDL` and acts as server for clients. And my server use this `WSDL` for requests to another server and acts as client for another server.

```
Client -> WSDL -> My server -> WSDL -> Another server
           |                     |  
           |------same WSDL------|
```

I need manage SOAP logs but I have problems. For example I can add to logback next lines:

```
  <logger name="org.apache.cxf.services.MessageExchangePortType.REQ_IN" level="ERROR" />
  <logger name="org.apache.cxf.services.MessageExchangePortType.RESP_IN" level="ERROR" />

  <logger name="org.apache.cxf.services.MessageExchangePortType.REQ_OUT" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="org.apache.cxf.services.MessageExchangePortType.RESP_OUT" level="INFO" />
```

But this way I manage logs for both incoming and outgoing messages.

Because my service and client use `MessageExchangePortType`.

**How can I manage each client/server logs?**

This is implementation of **client**:

```
    @Bean(name = "MessageExchangeClient")
    public MessageExchangePortType signingPortType() {
        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean jaxWsProxyFactoryBean = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setServiceClass(MessageExchangePortType.class);
        jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setAddress(host);
        jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
        jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
        jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.getOutInterceptors().add(new FaultOutInterceptor());
        jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.getOutInterceptors().add(new FaultOutInterceptor());
        return (MessageExchangePortType) jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create();
    }
```

This is implementation of **server**:

```
Component
@Slf4j
@SchemaValidation(type = SchemaValidation.SchemaValidationType.IN)
public class MyEndpoint implements MessageExchangePortType {
```

and in config:

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfiguration {

    @Value("${server.path}")
    private String path;

    private final Bus bus;
    private final MyEndpoint myEndpoint;

    @Autowired
    public WebServiceConfiguration(Bus bus, MyEndpoint myEndpoint) {
        this.bus = bus;
        this.myEndpoint= myEndpoint;
    }

    @Bean
    Endpoint endpoint() {

        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, myEndpoint);

        endpoint.getInInterceptors().add(new SAAJInInterceptor());

        LoggingFeature loggingFeature = new LoggingFeature();
        loggingFeature.setVerbose(true);
        loggingFeature.setLogMultipart(true);
        loggingFeature.setPrettyLogging(true);
        endpoint.getFeatures().add(loggingFeature);

        endpoint.publish(path);

        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

I want for example disable `REQ_IN` logs on client and enable on server but if I write: `<logger name="org.apache.cxf.services.MessageExchangePortType.REQ_IN" level="ERROR" />`

I set ERROR level to client and to server because `MessageExchangePortType` use client and server.

Answer (score 1):

Implement your own type of `org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.event.LogEventSender` and change the categories. Look at [`org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.slf4j.Slf4jEventSender`](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/rt/features/logging/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/ext/logging/slf4j/Slf4jEventSender.java) for the implementation that you are using by default to get an idea how to implement that.